# vue js массив с одним элементом-объектом

Tags: vue.js

```
<div class='bestsellers-item' v-for='(item, index) in items' :key='index'>
  {{ item.name }}
  {{ item.brand.logo }}
</div>
```

Имеется массив items, в нем хранится один элемент вида (brand):
[{"link":"/shop","logo":"123.jpg"}]

Но, если запрашиваю item.brand.logo - ничего не выводится.
Как стоит обратиться к logo, дабы вывести картинку?

Items: [ {id: 12345, name: name, brand: [{ link: link, logo: logo }]} ]

Comment: `{{ item.brand[0].logo }}` пробовали?

Comment: @MikalaiParakhnevich пробовал {{ item.brand[0] }} Выводилась просто скобка [

Comment: @Alex Вы уверены, что у Вас в `item.brand` объект (массив), а не строка?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar по запросу {{ item.brand }} выводит: [{"link":"/shop, "logo":"путь к картинке.jpg" }]

Comment: @Alex Ну вот проверьте, что за тип через `typeof`. Просто есть такая вероятность, что сервер отдаёт ответ в виде строки, а не массива. И тогда как есть, так и выведет, конечно. А ображение к элементу (`item.brand[0]`) и выводит открывающую скобку, потому что такое поведение у строки.

Comment: Если именно строка, то варианта 2: или исправлять проблему на сервере, чтобы выдавало всё как надо, или оборачивать в `JSON.parse()` (лучше через comuted свойство).

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Да, вы были правы, это строка. typeof item.brand возвращает string. JSON.parse(), не знаю как сделать правильно (не хватает знаний).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно нужен еще один цикл.
Попробуйте так:

```
<div class='bestsellers-item' v-for='(item, index) in items' :key='index'>
  {{ item.name }}
  <div v-for='(brandItem, index) in item.brand' :key='index'>
    {{ brandItem.logo }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Выводит множетство пустых дивов :(